# How to current portal user group odoo 12

Tags: controller, odoo, odoo-12

I want to check some conditions on the current login portal user group. I am in the `group_company_survey_client` group but still, it shows me a `False` value for printing the below code.

```
@http.route(['/survey', '/survey/page/<int:page>'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
    def survey_page_template(self, page=1, date_begin=None, date_end=None, sortby=None, **kw):
        User = request.env.user
        print('11111111111111111111111',
              User.sudo().user_has_groups('survey_management.group_company_survey_client'))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i think there is problem in using sudo with User.sudo() after applying sudo with user it get access of superuser and i think superuser doesnot have this group may be that's why it is showing false.

Comment: Initially, I'll try with it but getting same 'False' value.

Comment: Then your user doesnot belong to this group

Comment: from the user interface this user in belong to this group

Comment: My code work when I used 'request.env['res.users'].browse(request.session.uid)' instead of 'request.env.user'. Don't know what is the difference between them. both show the same value.